# MySQL - Use Variable column name

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple tables all with different columns.

For example: Table1 has the columns (Username, Group, Car, pet). Table2 has the columns (Username, Extra_groups, Vehicle, animals)

I want to Return the username that has 'Red' anywhere in anywhere in the 2 tables minus the username field of course. Now becuase each table has different columns im describing the table to find what they are then doing the following query however it doesn't want to work.

```
SELECT Username FROM $Table WHERE $column LIKE '%$search%'
```

What is the best way to query the columns without knowing what they are going to be and omit one of them from the search.

Comment: you tagged this as "mysql" and "sql-server". Which one is it? Those are 2 different DBMS'. "sql-server" is mssql and not mysql. You also need to show full code for this. your query's failing, am sure of it and have a feeling why.

Comment: not standing around like someone's personal valet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT Username FROM " . $Table ." WHERE ".$column . " LIKE '% " . $search. "%'"
```

Comment: I have also tried doing it this way and it just fails the query. If I write the query out exactly how it will be with the input vairables then in brings back the results. I even have both $Table and $Column echo'ing out so test they work each time.